# Trouble cleaning up after serving generated file from asp.net Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, filelock

I want to serve a dynamically created binary file from an asp.net web page via a http request parameter like so: `www.host.com/?Download=file`. So far I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.Params.Allkeys.Contains("Download"))
  {
    String fileStr = Request.Params.GetValues("Download")[0];

    using (Stream generatedFile = File.Create(@"C:\Temp\file"))
    {
      /* write the contents of the file */
    }

    Response.ContentType = "application";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                       "attachment; filename=" + fileStr);
    Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Temp\file");
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

which works, but C:\Temp\file still exists and I'd like it cleaned up. Calling `File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\file");` after `Response.End()` doesn't work, since `Response.End()` kills the thread. Putting the *Response* methods inside the `using` block, with `File.Create( (...), FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)` doesn't work, since the *Response* methods then fail to get access to the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing file to response you can call `Response.Flush` to make sure it was fully written, and then delete it before calling `Response.End`:

```
Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Temp\file");
Response.Flush();
File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\file");
Response.End();
```